# How to ignore files recursively in Dropbox using Powershell

Tags: powershell, dropbox

I am a Node developer, and want to keep all my work saved in Dropbox except for the big 'node_modules' directories. I found a Powershell code that selectively ignores a folder existent in Dropbox in https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files:

```
Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\yourname\Dropbox(Personal)\YourFileName.pdf' -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1
```

I want to create a Powershell script to help me find all 'node_modules' directories under Dropbox and then ignore them. I really need your help, because I really do not know much about Powershell.

Searching the Intenet, I wrote this little code snippet to recursively find all the 'node_modules' directories inside the Dropbox folder.

```
$BaseDir = "C:\Users\giann\Dropbox\IdeaProjects"
$NameToFind = "node_modules"
$MyVariable = Get-ChildItem $BaseDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.EndsWith($NameToFind)}
```

My question is, how can I combine the two code snippets? Can you please point me in the right direction?

Thank you, your support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're trying to recursively delete the contents (files) for all `node_modules` folders in the target directory? I ask because `Clear-Content` will strip out the contents of a file, but leave the file there. What you're probably looking for here is the `Remove-Item` command.

Comment: "I found a Powershell code that selectively ignores a folder existent in Dropbox" - are you sure? Looks like it would _remove_ the ignore flag...

Comment: `Clear-Content` is probably clearing the contents while also setting a stream flag on the content. OP wants `Set-Content` instead of `Clear-Content` with the same parameters.

Comment: My Gosh, I copied the wrong snipet. The question is now updated.

Comment: I made a mistake coping the wrong code.   Thank you @Mathias R. Jessen.

Comment: I got the info from this page: https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note:** `Set-Content` requires the `-Value` parameter. If you just want to set the stream without changing the content, use `-Value $null`. It will not clear the contents of your file.

You're almost there, you just need to use your result from your [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) command in the second block. You can also use the `-Directory` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate only directories and not files:

```
$BaseDir = "C:\Users\giann\Dropbox\IdeaProjects"
$NameToFind = "node_modules"

# Changed variable name for clarity, multiline for readability
$FoundFiles = Get-ChildItem $BaseDir -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $_.Name.EndsWith($NameToFind)
}

foreach($file in $FoundFiles) { Set-Content -Path $file -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value $null }
```

---

> **Note:** `foreach` can be used in place of `ForEach-Object` below but keep in mind the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1) used outside of the pipeline is a statement and functions differently than the `foreach => ForeEach-Object` cmdlet alias used inside of the pipeline. [Read this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/) for more information on the differences between the `foreach` statement and `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

If you don't care about using `$FoundFiles` later on, you can merge the last two expressions like so:

```
Get-ChildItem $BaseDir -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $_.Name.EndsWith($NameToFind)
} | ForEach-Object { Set-Content -Path $_ -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value $null }
```

---

For completeness and others who find this and want to know how to do the same on Linux, in case the Dropbox documentation moves the command to do this with Dropbox on Linux is:

```
xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 "$filePath"
```

I'm not sure if `Set-Content` will set file attributes on Linux as `xattr` does, but the above [`is how Dropbox recommends doing it`](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files).

Comment: Thank you so much @Bender the Greatest, this is exactly what I was looking for. It's important to me to ignore those directories because Dropbox gets stuck trying to synch those gigantic directories, and by design, every node project has one. My not-so-elegant solution was to pause Dropbox and stop sync, missing the whole point of having a Dropbox fo;der. Have a great day, and thank you again for your help.

Comment: @GianniFontanot No problem. I updated the answer to remove the bits about `Clear-Content` since you updated the question with the correct example.